# PHP web scraping - return content after javascript loads

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, web-scraping, goutte

I'm creating an applition that crawls a website, logs in to an account and accesses the user's travel information.

Once I login and go to the page that displays a list of travel cards, I need to click on the `View journey history` link.

**So here is the problem:** the `View journey history` link only appears on the page once a Javascript script loads (I'm not too sure which). When I run my crawling script and I print this page, I can view the `View journey history` link (because it loads the javascript on the browser). However, when I try to crawl this page to find this link, it doesn't find it. My assumption is that this PHP library does not have a facility to run javascript (a browser-side language) on the backend.

How can I return the page html AFTER all javascript scripts have loaded and processed?

I'm using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) to crawl. This library uses [Symfony BrowserKit](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/browser_kit.html) which is supposed to simulate the behavior of a web browser, it would be good to know if it has a facility to process javascript before returning the html.

**I'm open to any type of solution**, meaning the use of different libraries, or even a different programming language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've custom [`curl` package](https://github.com/mubin-khalid/spider/) for `Laravel`.

After login, you need to monitor the requests closely[use `Google Chrome's` Network tab.].

there are couple of scenarios.

1) website is making `ajax request` to some other url. You need to catch that `url` and send `ajax request` to that `url` to get data.

2) website is using `javascript` to render page data. In this case data will be already embedded in page source[`js` code]. You need to use `regex` to extract data from the page.

I only can this much of help without analysing calls, page source.

Comment: Option 1 saved my a $$. Thank you

Comment: glad that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

BrowserKit and PHP alone don't have the ability to execute JavaScript. There's a few options out there though; you could use something like Selenium and WebDriver or PhatomJS and automate things using something like Codeception (which is actually a testing library but could be used for scraping):

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver

The disadvantage here is that this approach is quite slow and may not be compatible with whatever hardware you're running your scripts on (i.e. a web server with no GUI or browser).

Another approach would be to use ChromeDriver which is a bit quicker and more lightweight than Selenium and WebDriver. You can then automate all of this using Laravel Dusk (again, another testing library but nicely suited for this sort of thing):

https://laravel.com/docs/master/dusk